# Ajuda nesse select preciso de uma cláusula para excluir registros

Tags: php, mysql, sql, query

Boa noite, estou precisando resolver um problema nessa consulta

```
SELECT * FROM campanha WHERE limite > '0' AND tipo = '1' ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1
```

Preciso fazer a mesma consulta mais excluindo todos os registro com um determinado login.. como proceder?

Nessa mesma tabela possui o campo '**USUARIO**' preciso verificar se ele é o mesmo da session e mostrar somente resultados sem esse login

Da maneira que está ele me retorna todos os resultados incluido o com o mesmo login da pessoa

Comment: O que te impede de fazer `"WHERE usuario <> '" . $_SESSION['usuario'] . "' AND limite > '0' AND tipo = '1'"` ?

Comment: ahaha obrigado meu estava brigando com isso ha algum tempo, sabe aquela hora que o cerebro da gente buga e nao anda pra frente! kkkkkk deu certo!
mais um problema resolvido aqui! thx (MINHA DUVIDA É SE OS DOIS 'AND' FUNCIONA! ELE VAI PEGA O TIPO 1 E LIMITE ACIMA DE 0?